# How to get attributes of a root tag using BeautifulSoup 4?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

If I do:

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup('<img src="a" />', 'html.parser')
print(soup.attrs)
```

I get `{}`. So I do the following ugly trick:

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup('<body><img src="a" /></body>', 'html.parser')
print(soup.body.next.attrs)
```

Is there a more proper way of doing that?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can get what I believe is your desired output with:

```
for i in soup:
   print(i.attrs)
```

Output:

```
{'src': 'a'}
```

EDIT:

- The reason why it didn't work before, but does work with this proposed answer is simply because **`soup` itself doesn't have attributes**, so `soup.attrs` is empty.
- The elements contained in `soup`, however, do have the attributes, so the `for` loop just iterates through the elements (only one in this case) and prints the attributes.

Comment: I guess then better would be to use as `next(iter(soup))`.

Comment: Presumably `[x.attrs for x in soup]` would also work